# How to caculate this limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt[k]{k}}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}
$$
what is the answer to this sum of limit? The numerator is hard to deal with.

Comment: What did you try ? Did you try to compute for $n=10$ ?

Comment: Maybe, discard a few first terms in the sum and take it from $k=n^{\alpha}$ with, say, small $\alpha=0.1$. The sum of discarded terms tends to be zero, and the nominator will be almost $1$ because it is $e^{\frac{\ln k}k}$ for $k>n^{\alpha}$, and the main part will tend to the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1(1-x)^{-\frac12}dx$ is easy to compute. Maybe I am wrong in some details but it should be something like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an idea
$$
 \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{\frac{\ln k}k}}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n^{\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{\frac{\ln k}k}}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=n^{\varepsilon}}^n\frac{e^{\frac{\ln k}k}}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}.
$$
The first sum tends to zero for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, say $\varepsilon<1/4$, because each term is bounded and the number of terms is strongly less than $\sqrt{n}$. The nominator in the second sum tends to $1$ for such fixed $\varepsilon$. Hence,
$$
 \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=n^{\varepsilon}}^n\frac{e^{\frac{\ln k}k}}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=n^{\varepsilon}}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}}=\frac1n\sum_{k=n^{\varepsilon}}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/n-k/n}}\to\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}=2.
$$
It seems that this is an exercise in calculus for advanced students. I am not sure that it is good that I wrote the answer here. Sorry.